# CoreData how to point on an entity?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities.

First entity A and second entity B.

A contains many B entities.

I add B entities to as NSSet.

My problem is when I add B entity to an A object if it already attached to another A object it removes from another A object as well.

Instead of it I want to just points on this B objects.

For example I add two A objects each time I add B object to each A object.

but if I already added B object to first A object and then I want to add it to second A object the B object will be detached from first one. But I want to save the link on this B object in both A object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have created a One-To-Many relationship when you should have a Many-to-Many relationship. With many to many, your categoryId will have a set of Artist objects, just like your artist has a set of categoryIds. If you add a categoryId to an artist, the artist will be added to the artists or artistsSet property on the categoryId. Therefore the categoryId isn't limited to having only one artist, and you won't replace the artist that was previously assigned. They will both be present in categoryId.artists (or whatever you named your relationship).

Comment: i modified question right now Artist it is A and category ids it is B, but thank you you are right!